# c++ having trouble storing tuple of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have an object 'S' that stores a simple tuple of pointers, which is made flexible by the use of variadic templates.  There are two methods, store() and store2().  The first one (store) works fine.  The second one won't compile because std::make_tuple fails with the error:

'No matching function for call to 'make_tuple'

It further adds that there is no known conversation from 'B*' to 'B*&&' for 1st argument (this error is deep in the tuple library header).

Code is here:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename...Rs>
struct S
{
    void store(std::tuple<Rs*...> rs)
    {
        rs_ = rs;
    }

    void store2(Rs*...rs)
    {
        rs_ = std::make_tuple<Rs*...>(rs...); // This is the guy that breaks
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Rs*...> rs_;
};

struct B
{};

struct A : S<B, B>
{};

int main()
{
    auto *b1 = new B;
    auto *b2 = new B;
    auto *a1 = new A;

    a1->store(std::make_tuple(b1, b2));   // This works
    a1->store2(b1, b2);    // How can I get this to work?
                           // (It causes an error in std::make_tuple of store2 above)
}
```

Comment: FWIW, `std::make_tuple(rs...);` works for me. I don't have an explanation for the error though.

Comment: Thanks -- this works for me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an error because `make_tuple`, like C++11-or-later `make_pair`, takes forwarding references, and when you explicitly specify template arguments that are non-references, those forwarding references become rvalue references.

So `make_tuple<Rs*...>` is `tuple<Rs*...> make_tuple(Rs*&&...)` - the parameter types are all rvalue references, which do not bind to lvalues (and `rs...` expands to a list of lvalues).

The whole point of these `make_meow` functions is to *avoid* having to write out explicit template arguments, so...don't write them.

Answer (score 3):

I can't explain *exactly* why it's an error (I suspect it's something to do with the mandatory decay), but `std::make_tuple` is not intended to be called with explicitly-specified template arguments (in which case you can just use `std::tuple`, rather it is for when you want them to be deduced).

Either of the following two works:

```
rs_ = std::tuple<Rs*...>(rs...);
rs_ = std::make_tuple(rs...);
```

Comment: By explicitly specifying types in make_tuple one inhibits template argument type deduction on forwarding references and thus, such an instantiation of make_tuple takes arguments by rvalue references (since specified types are not-lvalue-references). Because later on OP tries to pass lvalues, the error pops up, because they can't be bound by rvalue references.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that by changing it to `std::make_tuple(rs...)` it works fine...